# Graphing time with JS-Sparkline

Tags: javascript, sparklines

I want to chart the times with Sparkline, but it does not recognize it, or the graph's value always looks zero

My data points: [00:14,00:09,01:42,00:51,00:04, ... ]

```
<span
    class="js-sparkline" data-type="line"

    data-points="[00:14,00:09,01:42,00:51,00:04]"

    data-width="100%" data-height="80px"
    data-chart-range-min="300"
    data-line-color="rgba(70,195,123, .4)"
    data-fill-color="rgba(70,195,123, .15)"
    data-spot-color="transparent">
</span>
```

[image]

(Zero text appears when I hover over the graph with the mouse.)

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you link to the Sparkline library you're using?

Comment: @notthetup Of course, [Official webiste](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline) and [JS minimal file](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js)